# Yosemite, Lyx and Preview : it jumps to the first page

Tags: lyx

I just installed Yosemite 10.10.5 on my imac27 and I ran LYX.
I can view the compiled pdf file using cmd+T as usual. 
Problem is: each time I modify the file and want to see the result on the pdf, the command cmd+T return to document to the first page, instead of staying on the same page. 
It is very much annoying and make LYX very uncomfortable, I would like preview staying at the same page. 
After having that problem, I installed the last version of LYX (2.1.5), and of mactex-2015, but nothing changed.
Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What function is cmd+T bound to? On your second compile, if go to the GUI and click on the two circular blue arrows (looks like the recycle symbol), does that execute the functionality that you want?

Comment: cmd+T is in order to view the file in pdf (it is called ps2pdf) ; the command cmd+R do the same (pdflatex). The two blue circular arrows have another erroneous problem : it doesn't jump back to the first page but the modification you have made on the lyx file do not appears on the pdf. And if you click on the pdf file it goes to the first page, then browsing back to the page you wanted, you see that the modification appears.

Comment: That's to my knowledge something Apple messed up in Yosemite on Preview.app, and the reason I downgraded back to Mavericks.

Comment: @Xavier49 whenver you cross-post, please link to your other post. Here is one of your other posts: https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=mid&q=loom.20150925T145610-678%40post.gmane.org

Comment: It is the same question, sorry for that.. And thanks for the answers

Comment: morsbusg might be right. I don't have any problem on Ubuntu with LyX 2.1.5.

Comment: @morbusg if you have a reference for your theory that "Apple messed up in Yosemite on Preview.app" it might be worth posting that as an answer.

Comment: @scottkosty my "reference" for my "theory" is that before Yosemite, Preview didn't jump to page 1 on every recompilation (no matter how the PDF gets compiled), and after the update it did (regardless of a fresh install or not). IIRC there was some discussion about this somewhere here, and there was some roundabout way of not getting bit by that bug by using something like "continuous page" in Preview (cmd+1) (or maybe *not* using that, I don't recall). Either way, my point is that you can narrow this down to Preview on Yosemite.

Comment: @morbusg : thank you for insisting for having more details

Comment: and @scottkosty thanks a lot for those details. Althrough I am not completely satisfied and waiting for a better answer, it now works when in preference panel of Preview one uses "unique page" and not "continuous page". That said, I like it less, but it is much better than before...

Comment: @morbusg sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: @Xavier49 you might consider reporting the bug to Apple. If no one reports it, it won't get fixed.

Answer (score 1):

*Converting comment to answer*

In my experience, this has to do with Preview.app on Yosemite. You could either

1. [downgrade to Mavericks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/153134);
2. use only the "Show as one page" option in Preview.app, or
3. Use another PDF viewing application, such as [Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net)